# CSS for dynamic photos block

Tags: html, css, photos

Sorry for my English :)
Is there a way to apply css rule for dynamic content (album of photos added by users)? I want to avoid inline style because each photo in the album counts as one style=.

HTML code:

```
<div class="sys_file_search_pic bx_photos_file_search_pic" style="background-image: url('__imgUrl__');">
```

I tried:

```
.sys_file_search_pic.bx_photos_file_search_pic {
    background-image: url('__imgUrl__');
}
```

but it doesn't work.
Also tried:

```
<img src="__imgUrl__">
```

But photos are now unclicable and stretched.

My site: http://gracebook.pl.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle. It would be very easy to debug. jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

You can't define this using only HTML. You can output the link for the image using PHP.

You should be using something like the following

```
<div class="sys_file_search_pic bx_photos_file_search_pic" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $variable?>');">
```

where variable is the variable holding the URL of the image.

Comment: __imgUrl__ is a variable and inline html style above works perfectly. I just want to move this style="background-image... to external style sheet.

Comment: You can do similarly for the css. You just need to output php code in your style declaration
Replace __imgUrl__ with <?php echo $variable; ?>

Comment: Like this? `code`.sys_file_search_pic.bx_photos_file_search_pic {
 background-image: url("<?php echo $sImgUrl; ?>");
}`code`

Comment: SOLVED. I used `code`<img src="__imgUrl__">`code` instead. had to apply some changes but it seems to be ok now. (ps. link was in php file).